# Controller always pulls left in Need for Speed: Most Wanted (2005)

Tags: motioninjoy-ds3tool, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2005, xpadder

I bought the Need For Speed: Most Wanted (NFS:MW) bundle (it came with Underground 1 and 2, but I'm only really interested in NFS:MW). I've tried playing it with a mouse/keyboard, which works, but I have an Xbox 360 Controller I want to play it with.

I've downloaded Xpadder and MotioninJoy , but MotioninJoy doesn't pick up my controller. With Xpadder I've been able to put all the controls as I'd like but the one main issue is whenever the game loads the car always pulls left - I won't be moving left at all, but the whole car will just keep drifting left.

I don't know where to go around fixing this if there's any other way I can provide more information let me know. The controller works fine normally.

Comment: Just to try and clarify your question - you are using an xbox 360 controller with xpadder on your PC but you cannot make your car turn left?

Comment: Usually fixing this sort of issue (where the analog stick seems to always be moving even when centered) involves changing the analog stick's "dead zone" or recentering the stick.  I've never used xpadder, so I don't know if it supports that or not.

Comment: Xbox 360 controller i can turn it left but the car won't stop moving left by itself i can show you a screenshot http://gyazo.com/71e3e4cfa8d16ab8696c232eda5be381 you can see how its moving to the left and i'm not touching the controller it's just for this game

Comment: http://gyazo.com/a7310996da408d13d74c181576a96ed9 i put the deadzone up to 50% on both sides it's in the centre but doesn't help when in game it'll still go to the left regardless is there anything else i can try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like your controller requires calibration, so I made this image on how to do it.
[image: How to calibrate controller]

[image: Calibration detailed instructions]

Also, it sounds to me like you are using xpadder even though I am 99% sure NFS:MW supports a controller, thus it is conflicting with xpadder, because you are trying to control the game with both the controller and keyboard (xpadder).
Is there a reason you use xpadder?

Comment: So i went to calibrate and it seems it messes up with the Y axis and on the Dpad (usually i had the D-pad turned off because i thought it was because of that )                                                                         
http://gyazo.com/0ee306b72926a35e31ebbf810ae29d75 Y axis
http://gyazo.com/0aadaf38e41385ef89428f0c1d0267f6 D-pad

Comment: Just to add i've just tested it now on Dark souls and Deus Ex and it works completely fine so it's not the controller i can add controls to the controller in game now but as soon as i try it'll constantly be moving to the left and assign any key i try to Y-Axis so i'm stumped again

Comment: Woah, your Y axis goes up to 423%?! That's a bit much! I would suggest trying to unplug the controller and completely reinstall drivers for it. It could be a driver issue, software issue or perhaps the controller itself is broken, because each axis should only be able to go to 100%.
It's also possible that you didn't calibrate properly, because the instructions aren't very clear on what exactly you have to do with which stick, so I will edit more detailed instructions into my answer.

Comment: Okay i followed your steps on calibrating it and it's actually worked so thank you so much this means alot to me one of my favourite games and i can finally get to play it :D once again thank you so much

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to mark the question as answered! :)